# My selenium script (in Python) for chrome runs but does nothing

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, executable-path

vscode says it run but it does nothing. My pip is up to date and i installed selenium with the command prompt. i have a valid path (i think) for chromedriver. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "C:Users/P-Lou/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http:google.com")
```

The result is this:

```
[Running] python -u "w:\Python\Seletest\app.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.067 seconds
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "it does nothing"? Just from the code you posted, it is not supposed to do anything. Also, the url does not look correct. Instead, `http://google.com` should be it, I think.

Comment: it is supposed to open google but it doesnt. I changed the adress and still no responce.

Comment: Not a Selenium expert but it looks like all your code is telling it to do is go onto the Google homepage.  You may be running a headless browser in which case there wont be a visible window that pops up on your screen.  Try telling it to get elements from the page and examine what it finds.

Comment: its a good idea but it did nothing. i tried to run it in mcrosoft visual studio instead and mow my error message is:
Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Try using the following:
chromedriver = r"C:Users/P-Lou/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code by only changing the browser to firefox and removing the chromedriver = part and it worked fine, you might be running the browser in headless mode, thats why nothing pops up. You can change that using The `Chromedriver.options(set_headless="false")`
(not sure if that is the right code, you can check yourself [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options))

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) binary location being `C:\Users\P-Lou\Downloads` on your [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\P-Lou\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http:google.com")
```